# Passing arguments to python script

Tags: python, selenium

I have the following python code (script.py):

```
import sys
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

def message(to, message):
    """this a simple function to send a whatsapp message to your friends
    and group using python and selenium an automated tool to parse the HTML 
    content and to change the properties. 
    
    paramters:
    to - enter a name from your contacts it can be friend's name or a group's title.
    message - message to be deliever"""
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--user-data-dir=C:/Users/Miguelangel/Desktop/chrome-data")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
    options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)

    d = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:/Users/Miguelangel/Desktop/chromedriver.exe', options=options)
    d.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')                  # URL to open whatsapp web
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver = d, timeout = 900)         # inscrease or decrease the timeout according to your net connection

    message += '\núltima línea'
    # additional text to with your message to identify that it is send via software
  
    name_argument = f'//span[contains(@title,\'{to}\')]'        # HTML parse code to identify your reciever
    title = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,name_argument)))
    title.click()                           # to open the receiver messages page in the browser

    # many a times class name or other HTML properties changes so keep a track of current class name for input box by using inspect elements
    input_path = '//div[@class="_13NKt copyable-text selectable-text"][@dir="ltr"][@data-tab="9"]'
    box = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH,input_path)))

    box.send_keys(message + Keys.ENTER)
message(sys.argv[2])
```

Then I execute the following from the command line:

python script.py Test sometext

or

python script.py "Test" "sometext"

or

python script.py 'Test' 'sometext'

But none of them worked, I get: TypeError: message() missing 1 required positional argument: 'message'

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Your function `message` expects two arguments, you provide only one (`sys.argv[2]`), which is assigned to `to`. Therefore the second one (`message`) has no assignment.

Comment: I tought I can use `sys.argv[numberOfArguments]` to especify all arguments in one line.

Comment: This is **array slicing**. `sys.argv` is a **list** and `sys.argv[2]` returns the third parameter of your command line string, since arrays are zero-based. When in doubt, **print** the variables and see what you really get. But if you want to fetch the list of arguments while ignoring the first one, you could use: `sys.argv[1:]`. It means: slice the list starting from the second entry.
I suggest that you use [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html?highlight=argparse#the-add-argument-method) for more flexibility.

Comment: Got it. I'm using `sys.argv[1]` and `sys.argv[2]` now. Another question: How I can pass those arguments from vba? I want to execute that script passing those arguments from vba.